# How to create fallback if spring boot fails to create datasource using JNDI look up

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I have an application where we connect to database using JNDI which is set as

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/jdbc/mydb
```

in `application.properties`

We don't want to use profiles as client is not inclined to use.

However in my local environment we want to use H2 database instead of oracle, so is it possible to create a fallback bean if JNDI lookup fails?

Looking if something like below is possible.

```
@ConditionalOnMissing
@Bean
MyBean mybean(){
//configure datasource using datasource builder
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I already replied to you on Gitter, you should move that to a profile specific configuration as it is production specific. I guess your client doesn't want to enable the profile externally or something. You can enable a profile using `SpringApplicationBuilder`: that way the profile is enabled by the app and won't be in tests.